# Understanding grep --label=

Tags: command-line, grep, options

I am looking for an explanation how `grep --label=LABEL` works: Maybe somebody can give me an example [or two] on what `--label=` is for.

I understand what `grep` and `zgrep` are supposed to do – the latter is mentioned in the entry on `--label=` in the `info page`:

> ... especially useful when implementing tools like `zgrep'

98% of what I found so far is copy/paste from `info grep` and the other two percents the command is embedded in a script which I don't understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature makes reading the output of `grep` easier. If you want to check data that `grep` cannot read directly then you may end up using a pipe to feed grep instead of creating a temporary file which `grep` can read. If you don't want a temporary file (e.g. because it would be huge) then without `--label` you would have the problem that `grep` cannot print the information in which file the match was found.

This

```
echo $'fubar\nbaz\nbat' | grep --label=inputfile -H a
inputfile:fubar
inputfile:baz
inputfile:bat
```

is equivalent to

```
echo $'fubar\nbaz\nbat' > inputfile
grep -H a inputfile
inputfile:fubar
inputfile:baz
inputfile:bat
```

Without `--label` the first approach would not work (i.e. not deliver the wanted output) so you would have to do something like this:

```
echo $'fubar\nbaz\nbat' | grep a | awk '{print "inputfile:" $0}'
```

But this does not offer match highlighting in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer - now it makes sense! May I just add, for others, that `\n` in the string stands for `newline` when using `echo` [I wasn't sure myself and this confused a bit].